# plink pageant not working from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, plink, pageant

the problem in a nutshell:
running plink(with specific arguments) works from cmd, but not from asp.net

the command being executed:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" -batch abc@xyz ./fake_email.sh

from cmd, the command executes correctly, with fake_email.sh returning "0". from asp.net i get the following error:
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 sequence
Connection abandoned.

i think it has something to do with the user(which .net uses to start a process) not being able to "see" the key which pageant is making available. i am running cmd as administrator.

i am happy to post more info.

can anyone point me in the right direction?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it.

asp.net by default executes processes as "NetworkService" user. i was unable to cache the key for that user, so i decided to create a new user, which i assign as the identity of the application pool in IIS. because i created this user, i am able to cache the key in the registry (just using cmd).

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I'm running IIS processes as my own user account, and I still get errors.